# dreamweaver discards "find & replace" changes

Tags: replace, dreamweaver

I have a site based on a template in Dreamweaver. The template does have the tag: `<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/Main.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="true" -->`. But nowhere in the template do I have the "height" attribute. One of the pages I am cleaning up has a table in the main content area with numerous height="42" attributes that I am trying to remove. When I do a Find & Replace, afterwards I get the alert:

> The template that this document is based on does not allow changes
>   outside the  tag. The changes you made will be discarded.

So the 500 instances that got removed are returned. If the tag/search criteria does not exist in the template, why is Dreamweaver insisting that it does exist and discard my F&R? I do ***not*** want to manually delete this stuff, nor open Notepad++ every time to delete tags.

NOTE: This is just one instance of the specific error. I have also gotten this error message when I am removing whitespace from older pages in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the code?

Comment: @miah - For what I am searching for or the 1000 lines of page code?

Search Field: ' height="42"'
Replace Field (left empty):

Comment: The html, it would probably be easiest for you to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @miah - As I have never used that before and we have lots of php code (left nav, header, etc), do I just leave those lines out or simply paste the entire html file from Dreamweaver?

Comment: You should be able to just copy paste one of the files.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cableorg/YTGRG/1/

Comment: So I am drawing a blank. If you delete a couple of the offending attributes by hand (in dreamweaver) does it reject the changes as well?